# How to print "\'" in python

Tags: python

I would like to print in python `print("\'/")`,
expected output `\'/`

Thanks for helping me !
I just need to know how to print an antislash with a ' after thanks !

Comment: `print("\\'/")`

Comment: Use a raw string when the string contains backslashes.

Comment: And if the last character in a raw string is a backslash you'll still have to escape it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use either

```
print("\\'/")
```

or

```
print(r"\'/")
```

The escape character in Python is `\` and the option of r before the string represent the string as literals without the need of escape chars.

Comment: `r` does not mean "regex", although they certainly often are used for that. The `r` means "raw" and is used to create string literals. [Source](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/strings.html)

Comment: Tnx for the reference.

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you're looking for?

`print("\\\'/")`

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> print(r"\'/")
\'/
```

Answer (score -1):

The Best way to do this is to add a *backslash* (\) and then inverted commas. E.g.:

```
print('a\'')

a = 'That\'s a Sample Case'
print(a)
```